# Flutter IOS Workmanager Background Fetch Never Called in Production

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-workmanager

I'm seemingly unable to get background fetch working with Flutter workmanager on IOS.

I can confirm that it is working when called within xcode through debug. Just never when deployed to the device.

I've got my workmanager initialised and callback setup in `main.dart`

```dart
    ...

    Workmanager().initialize(
        callbackDispatcher,
        isInDebugMode: true
    );
}

void callbackDispatcher() 
{
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async 
  {
    function()
    
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

I've added fetch background mode to `info.plist`

```xml
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

I've added system capabilities to `project.pbxproj`

```swift
SystemCapabilities = {
    com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
        enabled = 1;
    };
};
```

I've added the plugin to `appdelegate.swift`

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Be much appreciated if anyone has a working setup.

Comment: how did you add the;
SystemCapabilities = {
    com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
        enabled = 1;
    };
};
to the project.pbxproj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. For future people reading this with the same issue, this does '*eventually*' work.

After having the app open in the background for ~48hrs, I finally got a background task to run. This is by no means a complete success as it is not really at the frequency desired, but this implementation does '*work*' none the less.

Just run in debug mode to confirm and be very patient.

Comment: if the app completely closed, is it working ?

Comment: @Pif No. As far as I'm aware if the app is closed on iOS no background processes work.

Comment: okay thanks for your confirmation, how about workmanager notification ? is it showing when its executed ?

Comment: @Pif if you have it enabled, yes, though with how Apple determine when background tasks are run you never know when one will truly show up